# Fitting density through regression model

Tags: regression, density-estimation

I found in a paper a way to fit a density through a regression model, and i wanted to know if you have some other referenes that uses it, or maybe the source of this idea. Here it goes :

Suppose that we have $i.i.d$ samples of a $d$-dimensional random vector $x_1,...,x_n$ coming from an unknown density $f$ that we want to estimate, on a given support, say $[0,1]^d$.

Construct $x_{n+1},...,x_{2n}$ from another candidate density $f_{sim}$(for exemple uniform on the support).

Let $y_1,...y_n$ be all equal to $1$ and $y_{n+1},...,y_{2n}$ be all equal to $0$.

Use a regression algorithm to fit $y = g(x) + \epsilon$ with a given error $\epsilon$, for exemple with a $RMSE$ loss.

Then, consider a given region $\mathcal{R}$ of the support. We have that the number of (true) points on this region is $n \int\limits_{\mathcal{R}} f(x)dx$ and that the number of simulated points on this region is $n \int\limits_{\mathcal{R}} f_{sim}(x)dx$.

If the region $\mathcal{R}$ become small enough, say a ball around a point $p$ with diminishing radius, this integral becomes approximately equal to $f(p)$ and $f_{sim}(p)$.

Finaly, since $Y$ is one for points from the true model and zero for points from the simulated data,

$$\mathbb{E}(Y | X \in \mathcal{R}) = \frac{n \int\limits_{\mathcal{R}} f(x)dx}{n \int\limits_{\mathcal{R}} f(x)dx+n \int\limits_{\mathcal{R}} f_{sim}(x)dx}$$

and hence at the limit,

$$g(p) = \frac{f(p)}{f(p)+f_{sim}(p)}$$

and we finaly have that :

$$f(p) = f_{sim}(p) \frac{g(p)}{1 - g(p)}$$

Hence, we estimated the density through a regression model.

This thing is quite general as it allows to use any regression algorythm to fit a density. Therefore, i'm looking for a reference on it. Also, if it's wrong, tell me :)

Thanks,

PS : The paper i'm refering to :

```
@article{article,
author = {Colla, Valentina and Vannucci, Marco and Reyneri, L.M.},
year = {2014},
month = {10},
pages = {},
title = {Artificial Neural Networks Applied for Estimating a Probability Density Function},
volume = {19},
journal = {Intelligent Data Analysis},
doi = {10.3233/IDA-140694}
}
```

Comment: Can you please link the paper you are referring to?

Comment: Added. Not enough character for the comment.